# How do I safely check JSON object for presence of property

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I need to filter incoming body data inside Logic App and react differently based on presence of `data.context.activityLog.eventSource`. I put conditional statement but using `string` functions to parse JSON document as a string to look for presense of `"eventSource": "ResourceHealth"` string within body. I'd like to use JSON parsing but how do I do it effectively something like `if (data.context.activityLog.eventSource = "ResourceHealth)`. How do I do it via logic app expression. Schema of incoming messages is completely unpredictable so there might not be `data.context` object at all

```
    {
  "schemaId": "Microsoft.Insights/activityLogs",
  "data": {
    "status": "Activated",
    "context": {
      "activityLog": {
        "channels": "Admin, Operation",
        "correlationId": "2b8e976a-f15c-4d92-81bb-25d28d542f86",
        "eventSource": "ResourceHealth",
        "eventTimestamp": "2019-11-28T19:27:39.357+00:00",
        "eventDataId": "f9dc6859-2899-4eb2-a6b2-7150acfbc478",
        "level": "Critical",
        "operationName": "Microsoft.Resourcehealth/healthevent/Activated/action",
        "operationId": "f9dc6859-2899-4eb2-a6b2-7150acfbc478",
        "properties": {
          "title": "We're sorry, your virtual machine isn't available because an unexpected failure on the host server. An unexpected problem with the host is preventing us from automatically recovering your virtual machine.",
          "details": null,
          "currentHealthStatus": "Unavailable",
          "previousHealthStatus": "Available",
          "type": "Downtime",
          "cause": "PlatformInitiated"
        },
        "resourceId": "/subscriptions/123/resourceGroups/test/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/NTTTestVM",
        "resourceGroupName": "test",
        "resourceProviderName": "Microsoft.Resourcehealth/healthevent/action",
        "status": "Active",
        "subscriptionId": "123",
        "submissionTimestamp": "2019-11-28T19:30:40.1798446+00:00",
        "resourceType": "MICROSOFT.COMPUTE/VIRTUALMACHINES"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What does "Schema of incoming messages is completely unpredictable so there might not be data.context object at all" mean ? Do you mean the structure of the data content is unpredictable ?

Comment: Yes, correct. this object may not exist so I need expression not to throw null reference exceptions and just gracefully fail if condition

Comment: Hi Gregory. Currently, you use "string" method to convert the whole data to string type and use "contains" method to judge if it contains "eventSource": "ResourceHealth" ? May I know what's wrong with this solution ? Why do you want to find another solution ?

Comment: Nothing wrong, just thought explicitly specifying property is more full proof

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the structure of your json data is unpredictable, so we can't use "Parse JSON" action directly. Please refer to my logic app below:

1. Here I assume your data is a string, I initialize a variable named "input" to store the data.
   [image]
2. Then we need to find the field "eventSource" from the data above and convert it to a json format like {"eventSource": "ResourceHealth"}.
   [image]

The whole expression is

```
json(xpath(xml(json(concat('{"root":', variables('input'), '}'))), './/eventSource')[0])
```

Now the variable "eventSourceJson" should be {"eventSource": "ResourceHealth"}

3. After that, we can parse the json easily as the screenshot shown as below:
   [image]
4. At last we can use it from "Parse JSON" in "If" condition, judge if eventSource = "ResourceHealth"
   [image]

Hope it would be helpful to your problem~

Comment: If your JSON contains a property with a special character like '@odata.etag', xml function will fail, I finally end up writing azure function.